# PHP : Not getting correct date difference

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am trying to get difference of two dates to count the duration of time.
This is my code:

```
<?php 
 $start_time = '2016-11-02 14:15:02';
 $end_time= '2016-11-02 14:17:02';
 $diff= strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($start_time);
 $duration   = date("H:i:s", $diff);
?>
```

So it is showing 05:32:00, but the actual result should be 00:02:00. I noticed that in result 05:30:00 added. I am not getting solution of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `gmdate` instead of `date`. It returns formated date string.

```
$duration = gmdate("H:i:s", $diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the defualt time_zone. I think you are using Indian time-zone . Thats why it is detting 5.30 hours more. Please see the below code

```
 date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
 $start_time = '2016-11-02 14:15:02';
 $end_time= '2016-11-02 14:17:02';
 $diff= strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($start_time);
 $duration   = date("H:i:s", $diff);
 echo $duration;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DateTime Class to get the difference:

```
  $d_start = new \DateTime('2016-11-02 14:15:02');
  $d_now = new \DateTime('2016-11-02 14:17:02');
  $interval = $d_start->diff($d_now);
```

Interval is an object which holds the difference in days, hours, minutes as public attribute (http://php.net/manual/de/class.dateinterval.php)

EDIT:
I just checked your code with some debug infos and it seems to work out of the box:

**PHP File**

```
$start_unix = strtotime($start_time);
$end_unix = strtotime($end_time);

var_dump($start_unix, $end_unix);

$diff = $end_unix - $start_unix;
var_dump($diff);

$duration = date("H:i:s", $diff);
var_dump($duration);
```

**Console Output**

```
php -f test.php
/tmp/test.php:9:
int(1478096102)
/tmp/test.php:9:
int(1478096222)
/tmp/test.php:12:
int(120)
/tmp/test.php:15:
string(8) "00:02:00"
```